# Two different (?) strings

Tags: c#, string

I've noticed a surprising difference in the behavior of two strings with the same (?) content. One of them was defined outside the method and the other was defined locally. Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {    
    string _outsidethemethod = "bba423c3dd784dff0908";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("myname:mypass"));
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_test_website) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        string auth_string = "Basic " + encoded;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = auth_string;

        string myAPI = "bba423c3dd784dff0908";
        if (myAPI == _outsidethemethod)
            MessageBox.Show("same");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("different");
        request.Headers.Add("api-key", _outsidethemethod);

     request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender1, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

     HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string xml_response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
     }
 }
```

The first attempt to insert the header with _outsidethemethod fails because "invalid control characters" are in the string. The second attempt succeeds (with _localvariable) although the string content is the same! I've edited to insert the exact code (except the username/passwords/keys). The only difference is that _outsidethemethod belongs to MainWindow and the _localvariable is a local string. Any explanations?

P.S. I've added a string comparison and the strings seem to be different despite having the same content.

I've tried to convert them to byte arrays by using:

```
Encoding.Default.GetBytes(thestring)
```

and the two strings give a different result. The first one (the one that contains the control characters) has 3 more characters. The character code is 63... When I convert them back to string with the same method, I get a string with 3 question-marks in the end. The rest of the string is identical to the second string... (the working one)

Comment: This behavior is hard to believe without the original code

Comment: Sounds like you had copy/pasted the `_outsidethemethod` content, and as other commenters have stated, you've grabbed some unprintable characters.

Comment: Try to test if `_localvariable == _outsidethemethod`.

Comment: The joys of the (in)famous "[Zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)".

Comment: In my pc it works without any exception... Both Add works.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile ! So how are you testing it ? `new WebRequest.Create()` ?! I fixed the code to make it compile and it works just fine. Please post a piece of the code that you're running.

Comment: Look at the source code in a binary editor - most likely, as Grant suggested, there are some invalid characters present, but not easily visible (this may be unprintable characters or for example a character that looks like `c` but isn't *really* a `c`). And note that you really need to give us a *reproducible* sample code.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the exact code. The website name does not matter. I've changed the keys/usernames/passwords obviously and I've added a test... The strings are not the same although they appear to have the same content.

Comment: @GrantWinney If I retype the code nothing changes...

Comment: @Sinatr I did and they're different! I can't reproduce it though in another project. I tried to create another project and define two strings the same way but the strings test to be the same! I can't understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: @Luaan Thanks for the tip... It seems that there were some additional characters. The binary editor was very helpful to find and delete them. Now the strings are the same when tested and they both work as expected. The question is how did these characters get in there? Before deleting them I tried copying and pasting and typing from scratch and nothing worked.

Comment: Too many possibilities. You might be using a bad file encoding, or an editor that doesn't work very well for C# source code, or you copied a bit of text from such an editor (very possible for something like an API code - if you copied from a web page, for example, there might be unicode characters like LTR or various whitespace) or some colleague might be playing a prank on you :) Note that `Encoding.Default` is your system's "fallback" encoding - seeing three question marks simply means that there are three characters in the string that aren't representable in your local encoding.

Comment: @GrantWinney No... I guessed that some characters might be the problem and typed it from scratch. I know it's strange because I can't reproduce it in a new project!

Comment: @Luaan I copied it from an email message. I'm using Visual studio 2015. I did find the extra characters and deleted them but I still can't understand why typing wouldn't correct the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually Luaan's answer but since it was never posted as an answer...

Using the binary editor (built in Visual Studio) I found hidden characters in the string and deleted them. Without the hidden characters the string worked as expected. It's strange though (and unanswered) that typing the string from scratch didn't work!